# Convert log4j 1.2 configuration related to JUL to log4j 2 configuration

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm converting an application from log4j 1.2 to log4j2. In the log4j.properties file I found follwoing configurations which relats to Java util logging.

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=SEVERE
```

How can I convert this configurations to log4j2 configuration ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Log4j2 provides a bridge](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jul/index.html) to route all calls to the java.util.logging API to Log4j2. To activate this, set the system property `java.util.logging.manager` to `org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager` and add the Log4j2 JUL adapter jar to your classpath (see "[which jars FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#which_jars)").

Then you configure log4j2 as usual. The log4j2 manual provides many example configurations.

The configuration snippet you provide might translate to something like the below (I added a FileAppender as an example).

```
<Configuration status="warn"><!-- use status="trace" for troubleshooting -->
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="FILE" fileName="myapp.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p [%t] %c{1.} %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="ERROR" />
      <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Does this means java util logs automatically route to the myapp.log file when the JUL bridge is present in the class path ?

Comment: Yes, all calls to java.util.logging will be redirected to log4j2. Then in the log4j2 configuration you can filter out events or direct them to whatever log file you desire.

Comment: Can you please bit explain what is the use of above two configuration ? because I cannot find any resource on this (I mean the log4j.properties)

Comment: The reason I provided an example of how to configure a `Console` appender in log4j2 is that your question configuration contained a `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler` which also writes to the console. I though I should show how to do this in log4j2. The `File` appender is just an example.  The configuration example should be placed in a file named `log4j2.xml` in the classpath. Then log4j2 will pick it up. Log4j2 does not understand the log4j.properties format.

Comment: Thanks Remko, I wanted to know the purpose of java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler I understand the log4j2 configuration.

Comment: How can I set the system property java.util.logging.manager in an OSGi environment ? At which level do I need to set this system property ?